# Determine the residue of $\frac{\tan z}{z}$ at $z_0=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having a problem finding the residue of $f(z)= \dfrac{\tan z}{z}= \dfrac{h(z)}{z-z_0}$ at $z_0=0$ since $\tan z=0$ at $z_0=0$ hence I cannot apply a proposition as it requires $h(z)$ to be analytic and nonzero at $z_0.$ I'm not also sure if I can use the Laurent Series for this.

Hints will suffice. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm not sure if the function has a residue. Looks more like a removable singularity to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to tackle problem which contains function with known taylor series ...(Or atleast we can calculate there taylor series expansion)

$\tan z=z+z^3/3....$

Residue is the coefficent of $1/z$

SO $\dfrac{\tan z}{z}=1+z^2/3$

SO it does not have residue

Note : If don't know taylor series expansion then also you can construct then easily.

I suppose you know taylor series exapansion of $\sin z $ and $\cos z$

$\dfrac{\sin z}{\cos z}=\dfrac{z-z^3/6}{1-z^2/2}$

Use binomial expansion for denomiantor and do some small calculation you get required

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: what's the residue of $f(z)=z^n$ at $z_0=0$ for different integers $n$? Directly integrating one circle is easy.

Now $\tan(x)$ is meromorphic and so has a Taylor series around $z_0=0$, so bring it in and go on from there.

In particular, what does $h(z_0)=0$ meromorphic around $z_0$ imply about the residue of $f(z)=h(z)/z$ at $z_0$?

Comment: I don't know how to answer the third question

Comment: Sorry this was unclear. If $h(z_0)=0$ is meromorphic around $z_0$ then using the results for monomials tells you something specific about the residue of $h(z)/z$ at $z_0$

Answer (score 0):

$\tan z$ is analytic around $z=0$ in the region $0\le |z|<\frac{\pi}{2}$, so it will converge in that region to its Taylor series:

\begin{align}\tan z=z+\frac{z^3}{3}+\frac{2}{15}z^5+\cdots\end{align}

$\frac{1}{z}$ is analytic everywhere except at $z=0$.

Therefore, in the region $0<|z|<\frac{\pi}{2}$:

\begin{align}\frac{tan z}{z}&=\frac{1}{z}\left(z+\frac{z^3}{3}+\frac{2}{15}z^5+\cdots\right)\\&=1+\frac{z^2}{3}+\frac{2}{15}z^4+\cdots\end{align}

which you can regard as a Laurent series around $z=0$ with all its coefficients $a_{-n}=0$, including the residue $a_{-1}$.